# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\Domains\xyz.com\wwwroot\123\index.php on line 26

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and MySQL.
When I run my files on the localhost, everything runs just perfect! But when I upload all files to live real domain I get this:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\Domains\xyz.com\wwwroot\123\index.php on line 26

This is line 26 in index.php:

```
GetApplication()->GetUserAuthorizationStrategy()->ApplyIdentityToConnectionOptions($result);
```

My web hosting provider has PHP and MySQL.

Any help is highly appreciated.

This is it:

```
function GetConnectionOptions()
{
    $result = GetGlobalConnectionOptions();
    $result['client_encoding'] = 'utf8';
    GetApplication()->GetUserAuthorizationStrategy()->ApplyIdentityToConnectionOptions($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Post the line which precedes this one. The actual error is probably there (like a missing quote or `;`)

Comment: `GetApplication()` apparently doesn't return an object

Comment: @JohnConde Wouldn't that result in _call to member function GetUserAuth... on a non object_?

Comment: It is working 100% right on localhost.

Comment: function GetConnectionOptions()
    {
        $result = GetGlobalConnectionOptions();
        $result['client_encoding'] = 'utf8';
        GetApplication()->GetUserAuthorizationStrategy()->ApplyIdentityToConnectionOptions($result);
        return $result;
    }
    
    ?><?php

Comment: @StillTrying Post it as an edit above, not down here in the comments please.

Comment: Which kind of framework are you using, maybe the configure file hasn´t be done yet for production.

Comment: And what are your two PHP versions?

Comment: Remote server may not support stacking the object like that. Have to separate into multiple lines. `$strategy = GetApplication()->GetUserAuthorizationStrategy();` `$strategy->ApplyIdentityToConnectionOptions($result);`

Comment: Hey what was the problem? I'm facing similar kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

This was introduced in PHP 5. Where ever you are deploying to really needs an update because it is running PHP 4.

Test case:

```
<?php
class TestingClass
{
    function test()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
function test()
{
    return new TestingClass();
}

test()->test();
```

PHP Lint v5.0.0:

```
C:\PHP500>php -l E:\testcase.php
No syntax errors detected in E:\testcase.php
C:\PHP500>php -v
PHP 5.0.0 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 13 2004 21:39:41)
```

PHP Lint v4.4.9:

```
C:\PHP449>php -l E:\testcase.php
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in <b>E:\testcase.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
Errors parsing E:\testcase.php
C:\PHP449>php -v
PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Aug  7 2008 15:04:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between - and >

```
GetApplication()->GetUserAuthorizationStrategy()- >ApplyIdentityToConnectionOptions($result);
```

This means "minus greater than". Remove the space.

2nd try: Is `GetApplication` really a function?

Comment: Sorry the space was only a mistake while coping the code here. Thanks

Comment: YES, 100% fine in localhost